# NUnit constructor values set to whatever

Tags: c#

Sometimes in my tests i do not care about construtor arguments values. I mean they have to be created but  is it possible to say nunit to fill out randomly values for constructor? Otherwise everytime i need to put values inside constructor argument like below: `10, "Eric"` where in fact i don't care. For instance for that test method i dont care about specific values nevertheless i have to fill it.

```
[Test]
public void Add_SomeAction_Result()
{
    MyService.Add(new Employee(10, "Eric");

    SetQet.Verify(uow => uow.isExist(It.IsAny<int>()
        ),
        Times.Once);
}
```

Comment: have a look at the Bogus library.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that NUnit has that built in. The [Bogus library](https://github.com/bchavez/Bogus) has a suite of random fake data generators for the purpose of fuzzing unit tests.